# URL GET method inside other URL GET method

Tags: parameters, get

I don't know if this is crazy but I would need to send 2 GET request in the same one. I mean, one GET inside the main one.

```
http://zzz.com?url=http://yyy.com?y1=value&y2=value&z1=value&z2=value
```

The problem comes when it is assumed incorretly by browser.

What's needed is:

zzz.com must receive

```
url=http://yyy.com?y1=value&y2=value
z1=value
z2=value
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can send a URL as part of a query string but you need to encode it first so the special characters don't get interpreted as part of the main URL.

For example, your inner URL

```
http://yyy.com?y1=value&y2=value
```

would be encoded as:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fyyy.com%Ffy1%3Dvalue%26y2%3Dvalue
```

and therefore your full GET URL would be:

```
http://zzz.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fyyy.com%Ffy1%3Dvalue%26y2%3Dvalue&z1=value&z2=value
```

You would need to decode that first parameter back to it's plaintext equivalent on the server side before you could then use it as a GET URL.

How you do this encoding / decoding on the client and server side entirely depends on your technology stack.

Comment: Thanks Starscream1984